# JavaScript Ajax call to PHP function not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

Following is the code for the javascript function after calling the function after removing the syntax error the error message is goen but the ajax call is not working

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function updatedb(counterid,table,team,feature,scenario){

        var DefectNumber = parseInt(counterid);

        alert(document.getElementById(DefectNumber).textContent);
        //document.getElementById("RunFilters").rows[5].cells[0].innerHTML          
        $.ajax({type:'POST',  url:'updateDB.php',data: 'postdefctnumber='+DefectNumber+'&posttable='+table+'&postteam='+team+'&postfeature='+feature+'&postscenario='+scenario } , 
            function(data){
                $('#resultdi').html(data);
            }

        );

    }


 </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You left a '}' from the end of this line before the comma:

```
$.ajax({type:'POST',  url:'updateDB.php',data: 'postdefctnumber='+DefectNumber+'&posttable='+table+'&postteam='+team+'&postfeature='+feature+'&postscenario='+scenario  },
```

And the data property should be an object as well:

```
data: {query: 'postdefctnumber='+DefectNumber+'&posttable='+table+'&postteam='+team+'&postfeature='+feature+'&postscenario='+scenario}
```

As "Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead." found in http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ you should not use 'success' callback.

Try to use this example instead:

```
$.ajax( "example.php" )
.done(function() {
alert( "success" );
})
.fail(function() {
alert( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
alert( "complete" );
});
```

Comment: @Renukesh Correct me if i'm wrong, but I think the `Function(data){
                $('#resultdi').html(data);
            }` line should be just `function(data){
                $('#resultdi').html(data);
            }` with a small `f`.

Comment: Thanks For the correction , the error is now resolved but still the AJAX call is not working

Comment: I could not see this working 
 function(data){ $('#resultdi').html(data); }

Comment: @ickyrr yes, the Function word should be function with lowercase f

Comment: Thanks for the correction , i have update the now there is no error in console but still the ajax cal is not working

Comment: Hmm. How do you know the ajax call is not working? Try to do a `console.log` inside your `success: function()` method to see if it really succeeds. or try logging your `data`.

Comment: As I can see the 'success' callback is removed after jQuery 3.0. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I created a pen with the working solution: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRWmKW

Comment: @RenukeshDeshpande is it ok now?

Comment: Yes the Ajax call is made successfully ,